# Trees using geometry nodes to effect density of branches in certain places

Tags: objects, faces, geometry-nodes

I am porting a tutorial on YouTube over to Blender 3 which uses completely different geometry nodes than Blender 2. This tutorial explains how to build trees with geometry nodes. I have my nodes set up in a similar fashion but upgraded to Blender 3.
[image]

The problem is that I can't get the trees to be heavier on density of branches closer to the top than on the bottom near the floor. As you can see when I move the proximity minimum of the ground plane up, the branches just uniformly vanish, they don't vanish from the base of the tree and slope upwards.
[image]

How do I get the branches the gently become sparser towards the base of the tree? I've attached my Blender file here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MwQSEO7k_9GNMa9YzRkptEVU2kF1Eyol/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Close, that was the thread where I figured out how to get branches completely off the bottom of the tree, but it doesn't slope up in density gradually. It simply increases an absolute threshold raising up from the ground. I want the branches to increase in density as you move up the trunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to "kind of" debug geometry nodes, it is always a good idea to check the values in the spreadsheet.

So i connected your distance to the output...

[image]

filled in a name

[image]

put a realize instances before the output

[image]

and i got:

[image]

so i thought: why is distance 0?

it is, because you calculated the distance to the trunk itself.

So i added a new plane, called it proximityPlane:

[image]

i changed this in your proximity node

[image]

and i got:

[image]

much better now!!

then i played a bit with the mapping values...these worked for me:

[image]

so i have more density at the bottom...

***UPDATE***

i know found your other question here on SE and saw parts of the video. So i made it wrong - just change the map to and map from values so that the branches have more density at the top than on the bottom.

***UPDATE END***

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Omg this is amazing!! Thank you so much for doing all of this. Is there any way I could have your version of the file?

Comment: of course, appended. Thank you! and...you are welcome!